# time.sleep alternative for stepper motor control

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pigpio

I´m searching for an alternative for the time.sleep() method.
Current setup: Raspberry Pi, DRV885 StepperMotorDriver, Bipolar StepperMotor.
A snippet of the code i´m using:

```
for i in range(200):
    GPIO.output(A1S, True) # Step Pin High
    time.sleep(0.0018) # wait
    GPIO.output(A1S, False) # Step Pin Low
    time.sleep(0.0018) # wait
```

I have already read through why the command is not suitable for this. It works, but it doesn´t sound very nice. I tried the Pigpio Modul with PWM but dont get it to run as simple as "now make 200 steps" or "make as many steps until someting happens".
Ive read that the Pigpio Modul has a delay funtion but I can´t find anything about how to use it.
Has anyone a code snippped of the delay function or can give me an example of another modul?

Comment: On a Pi running a non-realtime OS like Linux, you won’t get software to twiddle pins consistently with anything like the time precision you really need: you should delegate such time-critical functionality to either Pi hardware e.g PWM, or offload to non-linux dedicated hardware like an Arduino or similar. “Works” is far too subjective: in terms of stepper motors, try “ALWAYS delivers transitions with (say) 10 microsecond resolution” and there’s zero chance of achieving that when running Linux.

Comment: “Achieving”=>”Achieving that in software”